# Disable bluetooth Low Energy bonding 30 second timeout in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a ble peripheral in "just works" encryption mode.
After successfully bonding to it using BluetoothGatt.getDevice().createBond() , there seems to be a 30 second interval after bonding is complete (measured from message reception in the ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED receiver) during which BluetoothGatt.disconnect() does not disconnect.  I'd like to disable or decrease this 30 second interval.  I'm guessing that the interval is related to a period for PIN entry, however as I am using just works encryption no PIN is necessary (or requested by android).

To summarize in pseudo-code:

```
BluetoothGatt.getDevice().createBond();
....
//Bonding successful as reported by ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED broadcast receiver
BluetoothGatt.disconnect();
...
//30 seconds after the disconnect call the peripheral disconnects
//Note that if I wait for 10 seconds before calling disconnect, the peripheral disconnects 20 s later, if I wait 15 s, the disconnect occurs 15s later, etc...
```